# JavaFX: How to scroll to a specific line in the textarea

Tags: javafx

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    IntStream.range(1, 100).forEach(i -> sb.append("Line " + i + "\n"));

    TextArea ta = new TextArea();
    ta.setText(sb.toString());

    //how to I get line 30 at top of the visible textarea
    double someValue = 0;
    ta.setScrollTop(someValue);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(ta, 300, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

How do I get line 30 at top of the visible textarea?
I think 'someValue' should be relative to the total height which can be scrolled
But what is the total height that can be scrolled

**This is the result I want to achieve:**
[image: This is the result I want to achieve]

Comment: Try ta.wrapTextProperty().set(true); method

Comment: @DrashtiPandya how does that answer the question in the slightest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. We could just determine each line height and call `ta.setScrollTop((line - 1) * lineHeight);`, but we do not know what line spacing `TextArea` uses.

But I found that `TextAreaSkin` contains public methods for determining bounds for any selected character, we just need to know its index.

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    IntStream.range(1, 100).forEach(i -> sb.append("Line " + i + "\n"));

    TextArea ta = new TextArea();
    ta.setText(sb.toString());

    // TextArea did not setup its skin yet, so we can't use it right now.
    // We just append our task to the user tasks queue.
    Platform.runLater(() -> {

        // Define desired line
        final int line = 30;

        // Index of the first character in line that we look for.
        int index = 0;
        // for this example following line will work:
        // int index = ta.getText().indexOf("Line " + line);

        // for lines that do not contain its index we rely on "\n" count
        int linesEncountered = 0;
        boolean lineFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ta.getText().length(); i++) {
            // count characters on our way to our desired line
            index++;

            if(ta.getText().charAt(i) == '\n') {
                // next line char encountered
                linesEncountered++;
                if(linesEncountered == line-1) {
                    // next line is what we're looking for, stop now
                    lineFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // scroll only if line found
        if(lineFound) {
            // Get bounds of the first character in the line using internal API (see comment below the code)
            Rectangle2D lineBounds = ((com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin) ta.getSkin()).getCharacterBounds(index);

            // Scroll to the top-Y of our line
            ta.setScrollTop(lineBounds.getMinY());
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(ta, 300, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This solution works on Java 8, on 9+ `TextAreaSkin` was moved to the public package, so everything you need to make it work is to replace `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin` with `javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin`

Comment: It works the first time. When the scrollbar is moved and the code is executed again it will scroll otherwise. I've changed the code to: ta.setScrollTop(lineBounds.getMinY() + this.textArea.getScrollTop());

Comment: +1 for letting me know that there is a getCharacterBounds() public method in skin. I had a totally different issue, but this method solved it. Thanks :)